# what ports to open for Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase Admin SDK on my server which is hosted on AWS so it can talk to FCM to send messages to mobile devices.

From what I read , since Firebase Admin SDK is talking to FCM, this will be considered an outgoing connect and I will need to enable port 443 as a result.

Is there any other port that I need to open/enable so it works?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All communication between the Admin SDK and the FCM servers goes over HTTPS, so only port 443 should be needed.